# VBA Excel code not deleting "blank" cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have been using this code to define a variable of a range that contains data. I then tried to use it to clear a worksheet (minus the headers) but it keeps showing that the last row is A2, when there is "ghost" data leftover from a previous paste in range W4 for example.

Why isn't this code finding the true last row? Even after I run this, then go to Find Special > Last Row - it finds the last pasted blank range (which is "empty"). You can see the variable LastRow is always "1". In the mean time, I've just been setting the delete range to A2:W5000 because I know I'll never have that much data, but it would be nice to have VBA find the true last row for me and store in a variable. 
Thank you,

```
Public Sub ClearSheet()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) > 0 Then
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows,         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns,     SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        MsgBox (LastRow)
        MsgBox (LastCol)
Range("A2").Resize(LastRow, LastCol).EntireRow.Delete 'retains headers in A1:W1
```

Comment: I can't figure out this editor and how to format code!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35532472/edit

Comment: Why not just `Range("A2:CC1040000").ClearContents`

Comment: The rows have to be truly deleted, because this data is then exported to another sheet which an ancient program reads. If there are ghost cells it counts them and tries to work with those rows even though nothing is actually there (and throws errors).

Comment: Okay, `Range("A2:A1040000").EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: Try these five different ways to find [last row or column](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba).

Comment: Parfait, I'm actually already using one of those methods in my code above. 

Scott, that's what I'm doing in the interim, but I'd like to see how to find blanks stored as a variable.

Comment: I'm curious to know if
`msgbox cells(rows.count,"A").end(xlup).row`   ,will find the correct last row in column A, or `columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select` , will select even ghost cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try the UsedRange function. UsedRange includes "ghost" cells, and you can manipulate it to delete unwanted rows, excluding the header, like so:

```
Sub RemoveUnwantedRows()

    Dim wk As Worksheet
    Set wk = ActiveSheet

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = wk.UsedRange
    'Error handling incase there are no "Ghost Cells".
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, rng.Columns.Count)
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
    rng.Rows.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    'Proof that only the headers are left, you can leave this code out if you want.
    wk.UsedRange.Select

End Sub
```